# Batch script to change the icon of a shortcut

Tags: batch-file, icons, shortcut

I am fairly new to batch scripting and I am getting a little bit frustrated with batch files.

I would like to change the icon of a short-cut(on the Desktop) with a batch script.

I can't find anything on the internet. When you google this issue you only get result with "changing the icon of a batch file" and that is clearly not what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it pretty easily with vbscript. [Change Shortcut Icon](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/scripts/72657-script-change-icons.html)